# docker-compose service and the network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

Trying to get familiar with docker-compose version 2 and essentially just setup a 2 simple node cluster which can discover each other

given

```
.
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- node1
|   `-- Dockerfile
|-- node2
|   `-- Dockerfile
```

and a Dockerfile as

```
FROM centos:centos6.6
```

and docker-compose.yml as

```
version: '2'
services: 
   dn1: 
    build: ./node1/.
    hostname: dn1.foo.com
    command: tail -f /dev/null
   dn2: 
    build: ./node2/.
    hostname: dn2.foo.com
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

on running

```
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -it test_dn1_1 bash
$ hostname
 dn1.foo.com
$ ping dn2.foo.com
 PING dn2.foo.com (23.x.x.122) 
$ ping dn1
 64 bytes from test_dn2_1.test_default (172.21.0.3) ....
```

Are services discoverable by default from within containers ?
 Yes ? from [here](http://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/docs/networking.md)

I was assuming that the "links" attribute was required to make the containers know about each other.

How do i explicitly configure the docker-compose.yaml so that the containers can discover each other by 'hostname' ?
 Have tried links but that also does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem: when using docker-compose version 2, as you did, when you call `docker-compose up -d` your containers are created, and a custom network is created as well, which your services' containers are part of.

From inside this network, the containers **are** reachable and discoverable via their service name.

Smth bothers me, though, but I assume it's a typo: if you created services `dn1` and `dn2` like you did and you are in directory `test`, then your containers should be named `test_dn1_1` and `test_dn2_1` and not `test_dn1` as you wrote.
No I suppose this is a typo.

So you can check with `docker network ls` that there is a network created called `test_default`, and if you run `docker network inspect test_default` you will find your two containers.

Now, from inside `test_dn1_1`, you can run `ping dn2` and it should resolve.

Comment: I want to try and resolve my services (or data nodes) by hostname that I have set in the configuration and not by their service name. Is that possible ?

Comment: yes the container names are typo's will correct that